# Skipping or scraping <script> tags

Tags: php, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape some information from a web page with the Simple HTML Dom Parser. Some issues are causing elements with a  tag to cause an off set in my counters.

The tag looks like:

```
 // <div id="result-title-2" class="offerList-item-description-title">
                <script type="text/javascript">
                            document.write(getContents('#@UD9Jj\>2?E:4 9:;23'));
                        </script>Ro­mantic hijab
                    </div>
```

I either need to be able to get the contents or make my programme skip it.

This is how I am currently grabbing all of my Elements:

```
foreach($html->find('.offerList-item') as $element) 
        {
            $count++;

            foreach($element->find('.offerList-item-image img') as $image)
            {
            //$images[] = '<img src="'.$image->src.'">'.'<br>';//$img->src;
            $images[] = $image->src;//$img->src;
        }
        foreach($element->find('.offerList-item-description-title') as $title)
        {
            $titles[] = $title->innertext;
        }

        //foreach($element->find('.priceRange-from') as $price) {
        foreach($element->find('.priceRange-from')as $price){
            $pound = $price->find('text',1);
            $number = $price->find('text',2);
            $prices[] = $pound.' '.$number;

        }

         foreach($element->find('.offerList-itemWrapper') as $compare) //Get store links
         {
            $links[] = $idealo.$compare->getAttribute('href');
         }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Download html page to local disk after delete script tags

```
 $url2 = "https://www.idealo.co.uk/mscat.html?q=Dashboard+Cleaner";

 //Code to get the file...
 $data2 = file_get_contents($url2);

 //save as?
 $filename = "test.html";

 //save the file...
 $fh = fopen($filename,"w");
 fwrite($fh,$data2);
 fclose($fh);
```

After this codes. 
Try scrape and finally delete with this

```
$target = array('<script type="text/javascript">', '</script>');
$convert = array('<!--<script type="text/javascript">', '</script>-->');
$result = str_replace($target, $convert, $title);
```

Comment: Turns out it is what gets the product title so I cant skip, anything to scrape the inner text after its run and has the title? Thanks for the previous help

Comment: can you tell me? you scrape which page? I will try a few ways

Comment: This is the page:

https://www.idealo.co.uk/mscat.html?q=Dashboard+Cleaner

The issue is with the second item, the TOMTOM. If you inspect the title, you can see its generated using the same code as above. Thats what I'm trying to scrape.

Comment: I updated my answer. try last update. It's ok? scrape test.html in localdisk